# Whonix & TorBrowser:

Tags: whonix

I'm using Whonix in Oracle Virtualbox on a laptop running on Ubuntu 14:04.

A few days ago I was doing what looked like a routine update/grade to Workstation, when the computer froze before the update/grade was done. I was unable to recover without shutting the machine down. When I got back up, and restarted Whonix, Workstation told me it thought there were "package managers" running, and I should do a whole bunch of things to deal with it. I tried to follow instructions, but just kept getting into things I had very little understanding of.

In the end, I gave up, and started from scratch, reinstalling both Whonix programs, Version 13.

And here's the rub: after trying several times, the Workstation installation process cannot install TorBrowser for some reason. So I'm left with Whonix without a browser. When I try to use the TorBrowser downloader it's failed every time. The first graphic is the warning I get. It informs me that maybe:

- the download server is down (more on this later)
- File size exceeded (endless data attack triggered)
- I have no ideal what this means.
- Tor Browser downloader (by Whonix developers) has been broken due to upstream changes
- ditto

I have followed recommendation #1 over the last few days, trying again and again. No luck. I have checked News, and not seen anything. I cannot manually update, because I don't have a browser in Whonix to update with. The last bit tells me that the download timeout conditions were met, which, if true, would not have anything to do with the download server being down.

Is the download server down? Doesn't look like it--the TorBrowser download process goes through a number of steps, checking connectivity, retrieving the TorBrowsers available and having me choose one, etc. (See graphics.)

My download speeds from Whonix over the last few days HAVE been very slow--when I downloaded Gateway 13 et al, it averaged somehere in the neighbourhood of 100bs, while the internet connection between my ISP and me is 8Mbs.

Questions:

1. Could my problem have anything to do with the fact that I'm trying
   to get this done while in Cambodia?
2. Is there some way to change download servers, something I can do pretty easily in Ubuntu?
3. Can I change the timeout conditions?
4. Can TorBrowser be downloaded with Unix commands in the terminal?

Cheers! Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: I had an expat close friend living in Cambodia for a while. I made some testes with her (and with friends in Manila,  Maputo, and Abu Dhabi), as I am planning to write a white paper, and the Internet connection experience was very similar to what you describe - however the raw speed was another story - proxies, global IPv6 to IPv4 gateway, DNSes badly configured, traffic shapping, something is amiss. ISPs only sell you the Internet speed to their headend, and not to the outside world.It seems particularly obvious with that kind of speed that doing something useful is particularly problematic.

Comment: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Manually_Downloading_Tor_Browser contains step by step instructions on how to manually install Tor Browser. Iceweasel, a web browser, is already installed by default in Whonix-Workstation for such situations. You can use it to download Tor Browser. Use it for that purpose only.